# How to create a std::set with custom comparator in C++?

Tags: c++, set, comparator, std-pair

How do I create a set of pairs, the elements of which (the pairs) are sorted with a custom bool function? I write

```
set <pair<int,int>,compare> myset;
```

and get error : Type/value mismatch at argument 2, expected a type, got "compare"

I have defined "compare" as

```
bool compare(pair <int,int> g1, pair <int,int> g2)
{
    return (g1.second-g1.first > g2.second-g2.first);
}
```

and of course

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Method 1: use [functor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/356993/2589776)

Write a class that overloads the `operator()`so it can be called like a function:

```
struct compare {
    bool operator() (const pair<int,int> &lhs, const pair<int,int> &rhs) const{
         return (lhs.second-lhs.first > rhs.second-rhs.first);
    }
};
```

Then, you can use the class name as the type parameter

```
set<pair<int,int>, compare> myset;
```

### Method 2: use function pointer

Assuming `compare` is the function you want to use:

```
set<pair<int,int>, bool(*)(const pair<int,int> &lhs, 
                           const pair<int,int> &rhs)
   > myset(&compare);
```

Comment: You can also use a function. You just need to get the type right.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a functional object. Here is an example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <utility>

struct Compare
{
    bool operator ()( const std::pair<int, int> &p1, 
                      const std::pair<int, int> &p2 ) const
    {
        return ( p1.second - p1.first  > p2.second - p2.first );
    }
};

int main() 
{
    std::set<std::pair<int, int>, Compare> s;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since C++ 20, you can directly pass a lambda type.

```cpp
set<pair<int, int>, decltype([](auto &g1, auto &g2){return g1.second-g1.first > g2.second-g2.first;})> myset;
```